# Image doesn't show up in the absolute position

Tags: html, css

I have to put an image in the absolute position. This absolute position I make overflow hidden, so that it will height automatically, and of course, I make this absolute div inside the relative position.

But image only showing up when I change the position of absolute into relative.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="position:relative; display:block; overflow:hidden; float:left;">
    <div style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; display:block; top:0; left:0;">
        <img src="WEBbgB.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

---

SOURCE CODE

```
        <ul id="slideHome">
            <li><img src="<?php base_url();?>assets/img/WEBbgA.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="<?php base_url();?>assets/img/WEBbgB.jpg"/></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
#slideHome {
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    float:left;
}


#slideHome li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#slideHome li img {
    width:100%;
}
```

JS

```
                        $.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    var triggers = $('ul#thumnalHome li');
    var images = $('ul#slideHome li');
    var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
    var target;

    triggers.first().addClass('active');
    images.hide().first().show();

    function sliderResponse(target) {
        images.fadeOut(300).eq(target).fadeIn(300);
        triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
    }

    triggers.click(function() {
        if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            target = $(this).index();
            sliderResponse(target);
            resetTiming();
        }
    });

    $('.next').click(function() {
        target = $('ul#thumnalHome li.active').index();
        target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
        sliderResponse(target);
        resetTiming();
    });
    $('.prev').click(function() {
        target = $('ul#thumnalHome li.active').index();
        lastElem = triggers.length-1;
        target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target-1;
        sliderResponse(target);
        resetTiming();
    });

    function sliderTiming() {
        target = $('ul#thumnalHome li.active').index();
        target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
        sliderResponse(target);
    }

    var timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
    function resetTiming() {
        clearInterval(timingRun);
        timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },1000);
    }
```

});

The reason Why I make this position absolute is because this is for slider purpose.

Any idea please.

Comment: Please create fiddle, it has to work.

Comment: and right 0 and bottom 0 still doens't make it. The width may be 100%, but I don't want to set the height (or maybe auto)

Comment: If I set the height on the parent, it will make the image height follow the parent's height. I want to make the image's height dynamically.

Comment: @iyal, could you please paste the code, or create a sample in jsfiddle. That will a good view of you problem...

Comment: may I know why you use overflow:hidden ?

Comment: because removing that can make the image visible

Comment: Please, @humble.rumble How to not make the height of parent 100%; because it will annoy the element under it. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: No, I have solve it. I don't need the height. I just need the padding top as the height of the image. :)

Answer (score 0):

it will not show up because of

`overflow:hidden;`

and not because of your position

Answer (score 0):

apply

`position:fixed;`  into your image

```
 <img style="position:fixed;" src="WEBbgB.jpg" />
```

and that could make it visible

```
<div style=" position:relative; display:block; overflow:hidden;  float:left;">
    <div style="  position:absolute; overflow:hidden; display:block; top:0; left:0;">
        <img style="position:fixed;" src="WEBbgB.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```